# Conditions that guarantee the existence of a largest piece

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let $m$ be the area measure on $R^2$.

Let $S$ be a nonempty set of measureable subsets of $R^2$ ("pieces").

Define the *largest piece* in $S$ as:

$$\arg \max_{s\in S} m(s)$$

I am looking for **conditions on $S$ that guarantee that it has a largest piece**

(i.e. necessary and sufficienet conditions guaranteeing that the maximum is attained).

I thought of using the extreme value theorem, which says that a *continuous function* on a *compact set* has a maximum. To use this theorem, I need a topology on $P(R^2)$ such that:

- The area measure $m$ is a continuous function from $S$ to $R$.
- It is easy to define necessary and sufficient conditions for the compactness of $S$.

Is there any standard topology on $P(R^2)$ with these properties?

What are the conditions on $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard way of defining a metric on measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the following: $d(A, B) = m(A \Delta B)$ where $A \Delta B$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. If you identify sets which differ by measure zero sets then this defines a complete separable metric so compactness would mean closed and totally bounded. $S$ being closed is relatively easy to visualize but totally bounded is a little more technical.

Comment: However, the measurable subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, or even of a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$, do not form a compact set in this metric.  Consider e.g. the sequence of sets $$S_j = \{(x,y): 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1, \sin(2 \pi j x) \ge 0\}$$  These have no convergent subsequence

Comment: Of course they don't. Being compact in this space is rather restrictive.

Comment: It is interesting that there are two different metrics that can work. I selected this answer because it is easier for me to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The Hausdorff metric on compact subsets of a compact space makes the set of such subsets into a compact metric space.  Lebesgue measure is not continuous on this space, but it is upper semicontinuous, i.e. if $C_n \to C$ in the Hausdorff metric, then $m(C) \ge \limsup_n m(C_n)$, and this is enough to ensure the existence of a "largest piece".

Comment: So what are necessary and sufficient conditions on $S$ if we use this metric?

Comment: S should be a set of compact subsets of a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is closed in the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: That is, given any nonempty compact $K$ not in $S$, there should be $\delta > 0$ such that for every $X \in S$, either there is $x \in X$ such that $\text{dist}(x,K) > \delta$ or there is $k \in K$ such that $\text{dist}(k,X) > \delta$ (or both).